# 1/1 NotFoundHttpException in Controller.php line 268: Controller method not found. in laravel 5

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am trying to post some data into laravel controller using jquery ajax, but it shows error

> "1/1 NotFoundHttpException in Controller.php line 268: Controller
>   method not found."

and in console is throws

**"NetworkError: 404 Not Found "**

here is my code below:

in routes.php

```
Route::controller('contact', 'ContactController');
Route::post('searchDependency','ContactController@postSearchDependency');
```

ContactController.php

```
public function postSearchDependency(){

    //dd('hello');
}
```

ajax into index.blade.php

```
$('#deleteRecord').click(function(){

    var total = $('input[class="ids"]:checkbox:checked').length;
    var ContactId=[];
    $('input[class="ids"]:checked').each(function() {
       ContactId.push($(this).val());
    });
    //alert(ContactId);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'contactId: ContactId',
        url: '<?php echo URL::to('contact/searchDependency')?>',         
            success: function(contacts){                
        }          
    }); 

});
```

i already posted data using ajax to different method of another controller successfully this way, i already tried the possible solutions,  but don't know what happens in this case, please anyone helps me out.

Comment: none of the solutions works for me! this issue seems very strange !! i just made an edit to my code.

Comment: you have to use contact/search-dependency instead of contact/searchDependency

Comment: @user-4653387 Check the Update

Comment: @shock_gone_wild your solution works for me!! its beautiful! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the routes.php file contains the line:

```
Route::controller('contact', 'ContactController');
```

and your ContactController has the following function defined:

```
public function postSearchDependency() {
    dd('hello');
}
```

Then this function would be called by a post request to the url **contact/search-dependency**  instead of contact/searchDependency

This is due to transformation of CamelCase function names to more friendly and readable URL's when using Route::controller.

If you additionally define a direct route to your controller methode like:

```
Route::post('searchDependency','ContactController@postSearchDependency');
```

This route gets called directly by searchDependency in the URL (without contact before).

You can always check your existing routes and urls by typing

```
php artisan route:list
```

in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use static method, change:

```
public static function postSearchDependency(){

    //dd('hello');
}
```

into

```
public function postSearchDependency()
{
    //dd('hello');
}
```

Also, in your AJAX file you use strange:

```
'{{"contact/searchDependency"}}'
```

it should be rather:

```
'http://domain.com/contact/searchDependency'
```

and you should also change:

```
Route::post('searchDependency','ContactController@postSearchDependency');
```

into

```
Route::post('contact/searchDependency','ContactController@postSearchDependency');
```

in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a lot of reasons why such an error occured. 
First - is your route namespaced in the router? If not, then it is avaiable with url('searchDependency'), not url('contact/searchDependency') - check the route.

Second in your ajax request

```
 url: '{{"contact/searchDependency"}}',
```

This will return `url:  'contact/searchDependency'` , which is a relative path, not an absolute. For absolute, you need to use the url generator like

```
url: '{{url("contact/searchDependency")}}',
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `static function` instead of instance function:

So your dispatcher is not finding the `postSearchDependency` method since you defined it as static function.

**Work Around:**

```
public function postSearchDependency(){

    //dd('hello');
}
```

Besides in your index.blade.php you are using blade tags: `{{"contact/searchDependency"}}`

Modify them to :

`url : 'contact/searchDependency'` and modify your routes as follows:

`Route::post('contact/searchDependency','ContactController@postSearchDependency');`

**UPDATE**
Remove the `Route::controller('contact', 'ContactController');` from your controller. I was able to reproduce your error:

> NotFoundHttpException in Controller.php line 259: Controller method
>   not found.
>
> ```
> in Controller.php line 259
> at Controller->missingMethod('searchDependency')
> at call_user_func_array(array(object(ContactController), 'missingMethod'), array('_missing' => 'searchDependency')) in
> ```
>
> Controller.php line 246

After comenting `Route::controller('contact', 'ContactController');` out and modifying the `routes.php` and the `url` section in your ajax as i specified it work on my side.

Refference:
[Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing) ,
[Controller Dispatcher](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php),
[Router](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php)